# JavaScript Duplicate function names when declaring a method

Tags: javascript

This is probably a stupid question, but I am hoping to find out from someone who knows better than I do, is there any difference between the following function declarations within a class?

```
someFunction: function (obj) {};
```

and

```
someFunction: function someFunction (obj) {};
```

Comment: first its anonimous, the second are named, there is quite different, so its unclear what do you want know, please add details of your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a name on an anonymous function allows you to use that name *inside* the function.

For example:

```
var funcs = {
    someFunction: function someFunction(obj){
        // you can access 'someFunction' in here
    },
    otherFunction: function(obj){
        // you cannot access 'otherFunction',
        // you'd need to do 'funcs.otherFunction'
    }
};
```

Comment: if you give it a name, is really still anonymous?

Comment: @JonathanWilson: I'm not sure how you refer to it, but the function's "name" will only exist inside the function itself, so I guess it's still "anonymous".  I don't really know :)

Comment: I agree with you overall.  I'm just being pedantic I guess ;)

Comment: You may be right though.  Not sure if it still counts as "anonymous".

Comment: Note that you would need a `,` between `someFunction` and `otherFunction`, and a `;` at the end would be recommended.

Comment: @RocketHazmat first time I see this type of sintax, this can be usefull in case of recursion?

Comment: @Infer-On: Yeah, that's what it's most useful for :-)

Comment: Question: If you set a name, would the scope of the function change?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: The value of `this` (inside a function) is only affected by how a function is called, not by how it's created.

Comment: I suppose part of the question would also be, is there a performance / memory / efficiency difference between using an anonymous function and a named one, if recursion wasn't a consideration?

Comment: @Wige: I have no idea.  I don't think that's really something you need to worry about :-)

Comment: Well right now we are in the process of setting our coding standards and just trying to get the arguments for and against the anonymous syntax. My arguments tend to be against purely because (AFAIK, correct me if I am incorrect) the anonymous version doesn't show up as well in stacktraces when troubleshooting.

Comment: @Wige: I don't know which would be better for your standards/troubleshooting.